# compare value of form in view django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

**View.py**

class Register(TemplateView):

```
template_name = 'registration.html'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    form = CreateForm()

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

@staticmethod

def post(request):
    try:
        data = request.POST.get
        user = User(
            first_name=data('first_name'),
            last_name=data('last_name'),
            username=data('username').strip(),
            email=data('email'),
        )
        user.set_password(data('password').strip())
        user.save()
        request.session["user_id"] = user.id
        return HttpResponse(' Save successfully ')

    except Exception as c:
        return HttpResponse("Failed :  {}".format(c), 500)
```

**Form.py**

role_choice= (("Customer", "Customer"), ("Employee", "Employee"))

class CreateForm(forms.Form):

```
first_name = forms.CharField(label="Enter Your First Name", max_length=30, required=True)

last_name = forms.CharField(label="Enter Your Last Name", max_length=30, required=True)

username = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput())

email = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput())

password = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput())

role = forms.ChoiceField(choices=role_choice, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

class Customer(forms.Form):

```
contact = forms.IntegerField(label="Enter your contact number", required=True, )

amount = forms.IntegerField(required=True, min_value=500)

type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choice)
```

**Model.py**

class Customers(models.Model):

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

contact = models.BigIntegerField()

amount = models.BigIntegerField()

type = models.CharField(max_length=1)
```

*Template*

{% extends "home.html" %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}Create Account{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

```
<div>
```

```
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form|crispy }}

  <button type="submit">Submit</button><br>
```

```
</div>
```

{% endblock %}

After the registration when user select customer option after sumbit the form i go to customer page if user select employee option he/she go to employee page but i don't know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I strongly advice *not* to write all the views, etc. yourself. Django already *has* a lot of tooling inplace. It has a [**`UserCreationForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) that can be slighly modified. For example:

```
# app/forms.py

from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class RoleUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    ROLES = (
        ('Customer', 'Customer'),
        ('Employee', 'Employee')
    )
    role = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ROLES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        fields = (*UserCreationForm.Meta.fields, 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

We can here thus add the extra fields for `first_name` and `last_name` as well.

Now we can make use of this in a [**`CreateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView), and override the [**`form_valid(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid):

```
# app/views.py

from app.forms import RoleUserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class RegisterView(CreateView):
    model = get_user_model()
    form_class = RoleUserCreationForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        request.session['user_id'] = self.object.id
        if form.cleaned_data['role'] == 'Customer':
            return redirect('name-of-customer-view')
        else:
            return redirect('name-of-employee-view')
```

Where you replace the *`'name-of-customer-view'`* and *`'name-of-employee-view'`* with the name of these views respectively.

Comment: it show this error when i submit data. post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'form'

Comment: @MuhammadUsman: you should not override the `post` method at all. The `CreateView` implements the boilerplate logic.

Comment: but first my i enter my user data in auth user then i select customer table with foreign key if i only use CreateView method it just only enter username and password not other thing

Comment: def post(request, form):
        try:
            data = request.POST.get
            user = User(
                first_name=data('first_name'),
                last_name=data('last_name'),
                username=data('username').strip(),
                email=data('email'),
            )
            user.set_password(data('password').strip())
            user.save()
            request.session["user_id"] = user.id
            if form.cleaned_data['role'] == 'Customer':
                return redirect('new_employee')
            else:
                 return redirect('/')

Comment: @MuhammadUsman: you can add the first_name, etc. on the *form*, not the *view*.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman: see edit to add the first name and last name as well.

Comment: i add these thung in form in view i take value from user and store in model table mean auth user i make 1 class where i create 2 function 1st get where i call my form and 2nd is post where i store my values in db table using model

Comment: that's why first_name and last_name i use in view